# Turn off autocomplete on local host

Tags: html, autocomplete, autologin

I have a basic PHP based website running on a local WAMP server.

I am trying to turn the auto-complete function off the form, but am running into issues.

Code is:

But to no avail, is my syntax messed up?

Thanks Wayne

Comment: try `autocomplete="false"`, but i havent tested myself

Comment: Would adding a data list not mean each user would have to be explicitly specified? 

Im just looking to simply remove the autocomplete from the above form.

Its a simple PHP site that will only run on my local host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) ...

> The `autocomplete` attribute in a `form` typically has two effects.
>
> 1. it stops the browser saving field data for later autocompletion on similar forms though heuristics that vary by browser.
> 2. it stops the browser caching form data in session history. When form data is cached in session history, the information the user has filled in will be visible after the user has submitted the form and clicked on the Back button to go back to the original form page.

However, there is a caveat for login username/password fields where browsers normally don't apply this.

> Modern browsers implement integrated password management: when the user enters a username and password for a site, the browser offers to remember it for the user. When the user visits the site again, the browser autofills those login fields with the stored values.

So if you've saved the username/password login information in your browser by choosing to remember the login for that site you likely will still see them autofilled by your browser.

Here's a [link for removing these saved logins from different browsers](http://help.unc.edu/help/how-to-remove-saved-passwords-from-a-web-browser/) that might help.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 autocomplete lacks feature, why not use Datalist?
You specify a list of possible values for an input of your html form.

modify your form element to include type

```
<form list="cars" method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">


<datalist id="cars">
  <option value="Ferrari">
  <option value="Lamborghini">
  <option value="Porsche">
  <option value="Maserati">
  <option value="Aston Martin">
</datalist>
```

Of course modify the list attribute to fit your needs.